# Filter attributes of a class based on the type

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to filter the attributes of an object of a class based on their types.

The answer will be something around `inspect`, “list comprehensions”, `type()`, `__dict__` and `dict()` but I don't get it working.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.x = value

    def __str__(self):
        return "value = {}\n".format(self.x)

class T():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a1 = A(1)
        self.a2 = A(2)
        self.b = 4

t = T()
```

And I would like to print only the attributes of the type `A` in the class `T`

```
class T():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a1 = A(1)
        self.a2 = A(2)
        self.b = 4

    def __str__(self):
         ret = ""
         for i in [*magic*]:
             ret += str(i)
         return ret
```

Output should be something like:

```
value = 10
value = 15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`vars(self)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) to get a dictionary of the local attributes, then just test the values with `isinstance()`:

```
def __str__(self):
    ret = ""
    for i in vars(self).values():
        if isinstance(i, A):
            ret += str(i)
    return ret
```

`vars()` essentially returns `self.__dict__` here but is cleaner.

Turning this into a list comprehension for one-liner appeal:

```
def __str__(self):
    return ''.join([i for i in vars(self).values() if isinstance(i, A)])
```